# Foreign key does not work in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have an application in Django where I gallery and the linked pictures to the gallery, but on the side of the template does not appear anything.

**model**

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to='paint/%Y/%m/%d')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Gallery"
        verbose_name_plural = " Galleries"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Paint(models.Model):
    AVAILABLE = "Available"
    NOT_AVAILABLE = "Not available"
    STATUS_PAINT = (
        (AVAILABLE, u"Dostępny"),
        (NOT_AVAILABLE, u"Nie dostępny")
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='paint_set')
    paint = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to='paint/%Y/%m/%d')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_PAINT, default=AVAILABLE, max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Picture"
        verbose_name_plural = "Images"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views**

```
class GalleryList(generic.ListView):
    model = Gallery
    context_object_name = "images"
    template_name = "www/gallery_list.html"


class GalleryDetailsView1(generic.DetailView):
    model = Gallery
    context_object_name = "images1"
    template_name = "www/gallery_details1.html"

    def get_object(self):
        return Gallery.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).paint_set.all()
```

**urls**

Here is my urls: list of gallery and details with painters linked to gallery

```
url(r'^gallery/$', GalleryList.as_view(), name="gallery_list"),
url(r'^gallery1/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', GalleryDetailsView1.as_view(), name="gallery_details1"),
```

**template details**

```
{% for i in images1 %}

{{ i.title }}

{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Whats the contents of the www/gallery_details1.html template? If you don't get any error then it has to do with the template rendering

Comment: I'm telling you this because the by default the detail view mixin expects and actually passes a single object into the template view

Comment: @FanisDespoudis In template I have nothing, nothing is display. Please check my update

Comment: I mean the www/gallery_details1.html template should have a for loop over the object variable because judging from the **get_object** method it returns a queryset object instead of a single one

Comment: If images1 is empty it will print nothing. Can you trace the images1 variable contents?

Comment: I replicated your code on my machine. It works. Try to add this in your template to see if **images1** actually exists, `{% if images1%} exist {% endif %}`. Also, add django-debug-toolbar to your project so that you can see what sql command has been performed and what has been returned.